# What is the difference between "Window.history.back( )" and "history.back( )"?

Tags: javascript

What are the differences between window.history api vs history interface if I can use "window.history.back()"API or "history.back()"interface to go back a page?

Comment: Any global variable in the browser is a property of `window`. Thus, `window.history` and `history`, barring other context, are exactly the same object.

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference. If there is no defined `history` variable in your scope JS tries to find it on the outer scopes up to the global object which is `window` where `history` is already defined.

Comment: To be precise - if there is no defined `history` variable in scope your function, JS tried to find it in all outer scopes of that function, up to `window` object.

Comment: @Furman, thanks! You right. Worth mentioning.